Unable to call `BigDecimal.intValue` on Android
In a Kotlin file in Android Studio, the below code does not compile:
val x = "1.2".toBigDecimal()
val y = x.intValue() // expect this to return the value 1 as an integer

It says "Unresolved reference: intValue". But I can see that the intValue method is mentioned in the Android documentation and says it was added in API level 1. So why does this not compile?
My SDK versions:
android {
    compileSdkVersion 34
    buildToolsVersion '34.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "REDACTED"
        minSdkVersion 28
        targetSdkVersion 34
        // ...
    }
}


The intValue() method is there, its accessor is just renamed in Kotlin to toInt() so it better conforms to the Kotlin Number instead of Java's Number.

Great, thanks for that. Where is this specified? I don't see anything about that in the source code for BigDecimal. https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/refs/heads/main/ojluni/src/main/java/java/math/BigDecimal.java

Couldn't find an official statement for this either, sorry. BigDecimal is Java code that only has an intValue() method. When used with Kotlin this method is switched out by toInt(). If you use your IDE to go to the source of toInt() (try middle clicking on it), it will jump to intValue() in the Java class BigDecimal. There is only this one method, it's just that it is only accessible in Kotlin via toInt().
